# voltage range of ac signal

Tags: ac, dc, offset

I have an ac signal in the range of 1.5v-10v and it needs to be shifted down by 0.5v so it is in the range of 1v-9.5v. How can i do this exactly? assuming it uses a single power supply.

any help appreciated.

thanks

Comment: How precise does it have to be?  Any reason that you can't just put a diode in series with the signal?  That will drop the signal by about 0.6V - 0.7V.

Comment: @DwayneReid Hey, thanks for the reply. I thought of doing that but the signal shift needs to be as precise as possible.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that to add a positive Offset, you add a Postive DC voltage to an AC signal which gives the signal a positive offset. So to shift it down, what you will have to do is give it a negative DC voltage. You can look up how to provide negative DC to power an opamp, and use the same way to generate a voltage of -0.5V and combine it with the signal. 
The diode idea by Dwayne should also do the trick.

Another thing you can do is bring it down to 0, by adding a capacitor or any other way, so it fluctuates by an equal amount like normal AC around 0, and after that you can add the positive DC offset to that signal. But this will require more circuitry, but should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use difference amplifier with op-amp....connect your signal in non-inverting terminal and make a 0.5v by a resistance divider with your power supply and connect to inverting terminal..if you need more precise instrumentation amplifier is better.